# Invalid redis cache upon SQL Server update/trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, redis

I'd like to make use of redis as a cache for objects retrieved from SQL Server but we have a cluster of webservers and consistency is important. Is there any way to cache updates in redis such that when the row that came from is updated, the cache is invalidated?

In an ideal world, I'd be able to ask redis for "widget-123" and if I don't get it, I could load "select * from widgets where id=123" from sql server, create the object and store it in redis for future requests but if that row were modified, SQL Server would be able to tell redis to invalidate the corresponding key so the webservers will know to fetch a new instance.

Is that feature possible using triggers or SQL broker

Answer (score 1):

How about introducing a layer between your database and your code.The layer is responsible of following, with the ASSUMPTION  that all the cruds goes through this layer.

1. You perhaps already figured it

Request "Widget-123" -> | Layer (keys exists) ? get from redis : get from db and add to redis | SQL Server

2. Update/delete to the entity ( id=123) -> | Layer ( key exists ) ? evict from redis |-> SQL Server.

This approach can give you a good consistent result. But.

If you still want the sql server should push the details, sorry , there is no client ( SQL  is not general purpose ) that could tell redis to evict directly. But as @Jeremy Bell suggested, You can have a trigger which could write to a table and this table can be polled continuously(By quartz kind) and pushed the expire request for all the ids. But the disadvantage is that you may not get a good consistency, due to a write and read on a db temporay table may be a bottle neck or even problematic ( race  or deadlocks ) if not taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

[Can SQL Server send a web request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983599/can-sql-server-send-a-web-request)

You would probably push keys into a queue table and then use a background task scheduling framework like Quartz to poll for keys that need eviction.