# Using SQL Server 2012 to invoke an HTTP POST request

Tags: json, rest, post, sql-server-2012, restful-architecture

I have set up a NodeJS service that exposes a RESTful API.
This service has to be invoked by a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012.

I looked online for the feasibility of invoking a function via POST and sending up JSON to the service, but it seems like this cannot be done using MSSQL, but only after wiring it up with a .net application.

Does anyone know how can I use MSSQL to setup the HTTP POST request (setting header, body, writing the request, handling the response etc..)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If it cannot be done, why are you asking?

Comment: I think that it CAN be done, I just can't find the answer to the question of how. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can SQL Server send a web request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983599/can-sql-server-send-a-web-request)

Comment: Similar... There is no practical answer in that thread anyway.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue? Thanks :)