# Can I call a Web API from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, http

I want to send an HTTP `GET` call to an API every hour. I want this data directed to my SQL Server database (or MySQL). I'm a data guy, not a web developer.

Is it possible to make this call using SQL Server? If so, how? If not, what's the easiest workaround?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983599/can-sql-server-send-a-web-request

Comment: Yes you can. Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure/72395955#72395955

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure it's as simple as this;

```
     exec  [dbo].[APICaller_POST]
     @URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login'
     ,@BodyJson = '{"Username":"gdiaz","Password":"password"}'
```

After you deploy this CLR Stored procedure:
   https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer

It has multiple procedures that allows you calling API that required a parameters or even passing multiples headers and tokens authentications.

[image]
[image]