# How to call an API on Database trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I want an API call to be processed when a row is inserted in a table.

If this is not possible only with a stored procedure I happy to use some other technologies also.

Than end goal is to detect change in a certain database insert and call the api with that inserted data.

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: These kind of solutions create risk that your insert will fail if your API call fails. You're better off logging all changes to an intermediate log table (a queue) and then having an external process that reads from the queue and passes items into the API. This is often achieved natively within SQL Server by using Service Broker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can SQL Server send a web request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983599/can-sql-server-send-a-web-request)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure Maybe this helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure Maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way - Enable xp_cmdshell and you can call a process from within your SQL code.

You might first want to read up on why it's disabled by default though!!!

Alternatively if your api can be called from .Net you can write an assembly and load this into SQL Server and call this directly.

To be honest - I'd be surprised if your DBAs allowed either of these options on a Production DB.